# Field changed function on Item Fulfillment for inventory detail

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I'm trying to copy the serial # from inventory detail on a Item Fulfillment line to another field for further processing, for which I'm trying to do a field changed function via Client Script but not able to figure out the field trigger.

This is what I have so far...

```
function populatePIF(type, name)
{       
    if(name == 'inventorydetail')
    {
       nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'TEST', 'STATUS')
        try
        {              
            var inventorydetail = nlapiViewCurrentLineItemSubrecord('item', 'inventorydetail');
            if(inventorydetail)
            {
                var PIF = inventorydetail.getCurrentLineItemText('inventoryassignment', 'issueinventorynumber');                
                nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'custcol_serial_no', PIF);
                return true;
            }
            return true;           
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Exeception Caught', e);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In my own recent experience,  there is no trigger on the inventorydetail "field" as it's not really a field.

Line validation is also not triggered as far as I can tell.

Only option is an afterSubmit User event script.  This will be more reliable.